# shall i install xampp on win server 2008 enterprise

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

i'm very new (beginning) at programming and IT stuff, i may ask very stupid questions please don't hurt me :)

my question is that i want to run PHP+Apache+Php mysql on server 2008 enterprise but some how i couldn't make it work i did everything written on İnternet, and i gave up so decided to run xampp on server for local computer (intranet) shall i install xampp or can some body help me to run PHP+Apache+Php mysql on server 2008 enterprise, will xampp enough for at most 60 computers, there will be SMF forum, taskfreak, and a very simple address book.

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reasons that you couldn't xamp to run on the Windows platform is that you should've been using wamp (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) and secondly the windows' server is more than likely to be running IIS. Both IIS and Apache listen on port 80 for internet connections so there is a conflict going on there. You will need to either disable IIS or the wamp installation select another port i.e. 8080. Using this method you will need to specify the port address in your urls i.e. http://www.mysite.com:8080/

Comment: Thanks for answer, ill try wamp instead xamp (does x stands for unix?)

Comment: Sort of: lamp for unix systems, xamp for mac, wamp for windows

Comment: thanks jeff you are very kind.

Comment: Adding `:8080` helped me!